# Using a db query as a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use sql queries as promises. I can't seem to get it to work:

```
   query: (sql, args) => {
    if (args) sql = mysql.format(sql, args);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(Error(err.code));
        }

        connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
          connection.release(); // always put connection back in pool after last query
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            resolve([]);
          }

          resolve(results);
        });
      });
    });
  },
```

And here is the query itself:

```
async function dbCall(sql, arg) {
      let data = await db.query(sql, arg);
      console.log(data);
      data = data[0];
      return data;
    }
```

And here is the pool:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'db',
});
```

What I'm trying to do:
I'm trying to have it where it doesn't get hung up on async functions. I want it to return a value throughout a whole async function instead of inside of itself only.

Right now, it isn't working at all. However, when it is I would like `row` to be defined in my whole function instead of just inside the `db.query`.

I'm not sure if this makes sense, but if you need more clarification just ask anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I understand your questions correctly you're misunderstanding how promises should be handled. Promises make use of a `then()` function to perform something only after the async request is finsihed.

It reads pretty well in plain English. Perform my async request THEN do something with the data.

Try this:

```
db.query(userSQL, username).then(res => console.log(res))
```

Additionally, you could use an async function. This allows use to handle async functions in a similar way to synchronous functions where your code will be executed sequentially without having to worry about chaining and nesting other code inside of `then()` functions

```
async function dbCall() {
    let data = await db.query(userSQL, username);
    console.log(data);
}
```

As a side note. This was super helpful to me when I was first getting into Promises.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I've updated my query code, but I'm still producing nothing. I tried using 
`let data = await db.query(userSQL, username);
                console.log(data);` But it doesn;t produce any results. The console doesn't even return undefined, or anything. So I think it is getting hung up.

Comment: Post your updated code

Comment: I did, it's in OP.

Comment: I dont see anything I suggested in your post

Comment: Sorry thought I updated it. Updated the query. It now goes through, but `row` is undefined.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it... well kind of. Now I'm having the same issue as assigning a variable only does it within the promise and will does not do it globally... which is why I tried going the promise route to begin with.... so I am back to square one.

Comment: So you want the value that's resolved in the promise to be available globally?

Comment: More or less yes. I created a separate async function. 
`async function dbCall(sql, arg) {
          let data = await db.query(sql, arg);
          console.log(data);
          data = data[0];
          return data;
        }`

And I'm trying to call it here: 
`dbCall(userSQL, username);
                console.log(data);`

Basically I want to be able to user that data to compare and check for things.

Comment: Please format your code in your post so I can better read what's going on

Comment: Why can't you just assign a variable to the function `let results = dbCall(..)`?

Comment: Oh! Well... that should have been obvious, lol. But now I have a different issue: I just did as you said: `let userData = dbCall(userSQL, username);
                console.log(userData);` and here is the log output: `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: try adding the await keyword. `let userData = await dbCall(..)`

Comment: Not sure if that will work or not, just curious

Comment: `                let userData = await dbCall(userSQL, username);
                                     ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
`

Comment: okay so I just set it as a timeout... `setTimeout(() => {
                  console.log(userData);
                }, 100);` And it worked flawlessly.

Comment: right. that's probably not very good way to handle it. can you try doing this before you go with the settimeout method. `let userData = dbCall(..).then(data => data);`

Comment: Nope that way still returns pending... on a sidenote.. how exactly do I access that data? Because it is `Promise { data {}}` I thought `userData[0]` would have produced to the row data but it turns to undefined. if I did `userData.username` would also return as undefined... but it holes the data correctly.